# Optional parameters in Spring Integration HTTP inbound gateway path

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration in order to serve some REST webservice. The url of my service is something like

http://myhost/param1_name/param1_value/param2_name/param2_value

Of course, I don't have only 2 parameters, and I would like to have some of them "optional".

I have found a solution described in the following link http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Spring Integration. In Spring Integration, whenever I try to use the regexp [^/] to mach a parameter, this doesn't work.

For example, firstName is never matched like this:
path="/register/firstName/{firstName:[^/]+}/lastName/"

Any idea, how to achieve optional parameters using Spring Integration ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a discussion with Rossen Stoyanchev on the matter and he found your original approach wrong. Here is his words:

> The path is supposed to reflect the hierarchy of REST resources. Concerns such as encoding and content type don't belong there. They're cross-cutting and could apply to any URL. Just imagine a REST API that supports `/encoding/utf-8/format/pdf` on every URL. In Spring MVC we even support content negotiation by query parameter (e.g. `format=pdf`), or file extension (`.pdf`) as first-class mechanisms alternative to using the `Accept` header (based on `ContentNegotiationStrategy`). That's common practice and I can't imagine why anyone would think to put such information in path variables.
>
> He does have an example with `firstName` and optional `lastName`. I don't think that's a good idea either. First of all names can change even if not often. Also think of all the places where a person can appear in a REST API. Now you'd have to support `firstName` with optional `lastName` everywhere. E.g. `/person/{firstName}/{lastName}/children/{firstName}/{lastName}`.
>
> Seems like both examples are trying to put random data in the URL path that belongs to query parameters or the request body. **The path should reflect hierarchy of resources**
>
> BTW the referenced article actually says JAX-RS doesn't support optional path variables. He describes it as a hack.

So, would be better if you can move those `optinal` parts to the request params and have some generic `path` to map them all. Or... `@RequestMapping` has `params` option to allow map the method to the URL, if it contains or not specific params.